# How to work with uint8_t instead of char?

Tags: c++, char, reinterpret-cast, uint8t

I wish to understand the situation regarding uint8_t vs char, portability, bit-manipulation, the best practices, state of affairs, etc. Do you know a good reading on the topic?

I wish to do byte-IO. But of course char has a more complicated and subtle definition than uint8_t; which I assume was one of the reasons for introducing stdint header.

However, I had problems using uint8_t on multiple occasions. A few months ago, once, because iostreams are not defined for uint8_t. Isn't there a C++ library doing really-well-defined-byte-IO i.e. read and write uint8_t? If not, I assume there is no demand for it. Why?

My latest headache stems from the failure of this code to compile:

```
uint8_t read(decltype(cin) & s)
{
    char c;
    s.get(c);
    return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t>(c);
}

error: invalid cast from type 'char' to type 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}'
```

Why the error? How to make this work?

Comment: Hmm.  Use static_cast<> instead.

Comment: `decltype(cin)` seems insane. You really want `std::istream &` there, nothing else.

Comment: static_cast preserves numerical value by possibly using a runtime conversion if I am not mistaken, I want to preserve the exact bit-sequence (I am reading the MBR of a disk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general, portable, roundtrip-correct way would be to:

1. demand in your API that all byte values can be expressed with at most 8 bits,
2. use the layout-compatibility of `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` for I/O, and
3. convert `unsigned char` to `uint8_t` as needed.

For example:

```
bool read_one_byte(std::istream & is, uint8_t * out)
{
    unsigned char x;    // a "byte" on your system 
    if (is.get(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x)))
    {
        *out = x;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool write_one_byte(std::ostream & os, uint8_t val)
{
    unsigned char x = val;
    return os.write(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&x), 1);
}
```

Some explanation: Rule 1 guarantees that values can be round-trip converted between `uint8_t` and `unsigned char` without losing information. Rule 2 means that we can use the iostream I/O operations on `unsigned char` variables, even though they're expressed in terms of `char`s.

We could also have used `is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x), 1)` instead of `is.get()`  for symmetry. (Using `read` in general, for stream counts larger than 1, also requires the use of `gcount()` on error, but that doesn't apply here.)

As always, you must never ignore the return value of I/O operations. Doing so is always a bug in your program.

Comment: It is relevant to the questions because in the question comments use of static_cast is discussed but OP says it is unsuitable, as do you. But I don't understand why.

Comment: @NeilKirk static_cast reinterpret_cast and dynamic_cast are used primarily for documenting programmers intent, the actual effect on the code might be the same in some but not in all cases

Comment: @Kerrek What is the technical reason for the compiler error? Why can't I sedate the type-system and reinterpret a char as a uint8_t? Why do I need a whole pointer to get an a single byte out?

Answer (score 0):

> A few months ago, once, because iostreams are not defined for uint8_t.

`uint8_t` is pretty much just a typedef for `unsigned char`. In fact, i doubt you could find a machine where it isn't.

```
uint8_t read(decltype(cin) & s)
{
    char c;
    s.get(c);
    return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t>(c);
}
```

Using `decltype(cin)` instead of `std::istream` has no advantage at all, it is just a potential source of confusion.
The cast in the `return`-statement isn't necessary; converting a `char` into an `unsigned char` works implicitly.

> A few months ago, once, because iostreams are not defined for uint8_t.

They are. Not for `uint8_t` itself, but most certainly for the type it actually represents. operator>> is overloaded for `unsigned char`. This code works:

```
uint8_t read(istream& s)
{
    return s.get();
}
```

Since `unsigned char` and `char` can alias each other you can also just `reinterpret_cast` any pointer to a `char` string to an `unsigned char*` and work with that.

In case you want the most portable way possible take a look at Kerreks answer.

Comment: "Since unsigned char and char can alias each other" can you explain?

Comment: @NeilKirk According to [basic.lval]/10 you can access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of type `char` or `unsigned char`. So you can access any stored element of a `char` array through a glvalue of type `unsigned char`. You can also modify those elements through such a glvalue and access them with a `char`-glvalue again.